# How to extend the string class in c# to change its behavior?

Tags: c#, string

I don't like the way string behaves and there are a few other things I would like to change.

It appears string cannot be extended because it is a sealed class.

Is there another way? I could copy the source code and make my own class but then it wouldn't be compatible with string, or could I make it compatible?

Comment: What sort of features are you after? You could use Extension methods to provide extra behaviors to string types but it would be interesting to know what you expect it to behave like.

Comment: You can't extend a sealed class. You can define some extension methods, of course, but this is far from "extending" the class. The answer to your question depends entirely on what exactly you don't like and you want to change. But most likely, it'll be best if you declare a new class that contains a string but offers different operations.

Comment: I doubt you could copy source code either - the compiler does many special things with `string` (e.g. interning) that could not be replicated with source code.

Comment: What specific behavior(s) do you not like?

Comment: Standard way (using extension methods) is covered in linked duplicate. If your needs go beyond that - make sure to update the post with clarification like "I know I can use XXXX, but it does not give me way to do YYY. I tried ZZZ but it sucks".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use extension methods to extend String. The link below explains  extension methods and has an example of how to add a WordCount() function to String.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: this is right. 'String' > 'string'

Comment: @drooksy Huh?  `String` == `string`

Comment: @DStanley clearly `"String" > "string"` :) (no idea what drooksy meant really)